# Using "www.pgyer.com" To Test Applications On iOS Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, jailbreak, provisioning-profile

Regarding www.pgyer.com, I'm just asking whether the upload procedures for iOS apps will include signing the app so to run on non-jailbroken devices, or signing should be done manually? In other words, do I have to enroll in the developer program, which is $99/year, or I can test my applications without that by just uploading my application to the site? If the certificate is not needed, then I made a simple application in xCode without signing it with a certain developer certificate, but I cannot install that application on my non-jailbroken iPhone 4S that is running iOS 8.2. I just need the correct way for doing the signing, and uploading, to the site, if it really does not need the developer certificate. But, if the certificate is needed, then I'm wondering what is the site's services useful for?

Please, I really need help for using this site to test my applications on my iPhone for free, if it offers that.

Comment: have tried to install any app showing it's library? I don't think without registering you device udid with provisioning profile, you can install the app for testing purpose.

Comment: I didn't get your comment. More explanations, please.

Comment: Have you tried to install any app present here, http://www.pgyer.com/app/recent ?

Comment: Yes. I've uploaded an application for testing, and I made it public, and it was shown on the recent testing page. But when I download it, and eventually install it, it gives me the error that it cannot be installed at this time.

Comment: So, my point is, is there any free way where I can test my applications on my non-jailbroken device without having to pay the 99$/year subscription?

Comment: you have created a simulator build or device build. making device build without provisioning profile is not possible.

Comment: So you need a valid provisioning and certificate from apple developer program.

Comment: Ok, now what is the point again from www.pgyer.com again if it needs a provision certificate?

Comment: i believe yes, you need certificate and this site is some how simmiler to TestFlight.

Comment: you should be able to run on your own device via Xcode right? If you need over the air installation, then you need a paid developer account.